# Is it safe to use my Indian MacBook Pro charger in America using a simple adapter?

Tags: mac, compatibility, charger

[image]

I am using a local adapter to use my Indian MacBook charger in the US. I am wondering is it safe to use so.

Comment: I had a strange experience: I bought 2x OEM chargers, in India (exactly as pictured).  They did work perfectly in India. Strangely, in the US they don't work!  It could be an incredible coincidence that they both broke during an airplane flight.  But maybe they only work on Indian power (220V, 60hz) and won't work on US power?  (Usually 110V 50hz.)  Strange one!

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely fine, so long as the original to adapter interface makes a good connection.

Alternatively, you could try to find a specific flat pin adapter to run directly from the charger - this is just a simple eBay UK search with similar plugs … http://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/apple-us-plug